# Reallocating Iterators [REWRITTEN]

Tags: c++, iterator

How would you insert at a certain location in an STL vector?

So far, I have tried inserting into an STL vector like so:

```
someVector.insert(someVector.begin() + location, info);
```

This works when I'm inserting items in sequence, but when I delete an item from the vector, I want to be able to insert at that location. However, the iterator needs to be reallocated since it throws a "vector iterator + offset out of range" error. (I'm pretty new to C++ iterators, so I'm not entirely sure what "iterator reallocation" is and can't seem to find a good explanation, so if you can explain, please feel free!) I can find a lot of questions that ask when the iterator needs to be reallocated but not on the best way to do so. Alternatively, would there be a different/better way to insert at a position?

Comment: You need to use a different container. If you're fighting against the tide like that, you need to reexamine your assumptions. Perhaps a vector isn't the right container.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "reallocating" an iterator.

Answer (score 2):

The erase operation on a vector returns the iterator one past the just-erased element. You can use that iterator as the subsequent insertion position to insert "at the place" where you erased:

```
auto it = v.begin() + 3;  // say

it = v.erase(it);         // erase and store position
v.insert(it, -3);         // insert at that position
```